# What is the best way to add categories to posts - Ruby on Rails blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby and Rails so bear with me please. I have created a very simple blog application with both posts and comments. Everything works great. My next question regarding adding categories. I am wondering the best way to do this. As I can't see too far in front of me yet when it comes to Rails I thought I would ask.

To be clear, I would like that a single post can have multiple categories and a category can have multiple posts.

Is the best way to do this to create a 'categories' table and then use the posts and categories models to do `has_many :posts`, `has_many :categories`? Would I also then set the `routes.rb` such that posts are embedded under categories?

Or is there an easier way by simply adding a category column to the existing posts table? (in which case I would imagine having multiple categories would be difficult).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you want a many-to-many relationship between categories and posts, I would (and do) use a tagging plugin such as [ActsAsTaggableOn](http://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on), where you can define what a "tag" is referred to, and call it "category." Simple and effective. In your form, you can limit the possible values for a "tag" with a whitelist (like, "coding," "recipes," "vacation") for your different categories.

Answer (score 19):

It depends how much effort you're willing to put in - you *could* use a tagging plugin, or set up a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship in both the Posts and Categories models, but I'd recommend something a bit different.

If you create a third model, "Categorizations", as a kind of "glue" beween Posts and Categories, you can have more control. Post `has_many :categories :through => categorizations` and Category `has_many :posts :through => :categorizations`

A benefit of this is that your categories aren't stored in your code, but rather in the database - so adding/removing/editing them doesn't require you to modify any source code. How you set up the routes is completely up to you - you could have `/categories/:id` return a list of all posts that belong to that category, or implement some kind of search form using one or more categories as parameters.

Ryan Bates has an [excellent screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many) explaining all of this, with several different ways of tackling the problem.

I know you mentioned you're new to RoR, so I apologise if this is a little complicated for what you want. As I said, a plugin might be best for your needs, but I find it's always nice to have coded it yourself if possible, with the added benefit of having more flexibility and control :)